# Double interaction with cell fracture

Tags: modeling, keyframes, constraints, rigid-body-simulation, cell-fracture

what is driving me crazy right now is that I want to animate a vase that is pushed off a pedestal and when it hits the ground it breaks into pieces. To break the vase into fragments I used the cell fracture add on, the problem is that the vase must not break as soon as it undergoes the first impact (i.e. when pushed by the pedestal) but that it breaks at the moment of its second interaction (i.e. with the ground). Do you have any ideas on what I can do? Thanks in advance

Comment: My first thought is several stiff constraints on a central empty, but that may not work. My second thought is that you animate a whole vase falling, and then replace it with the fractured vase later in animation.

Answer (score 2):

This was written for those with reasonable experience...

The Blend file will be posted up if asked for but it won't help a lot because everything ends up baked & keyframed.

[image]

Vases don't actually bounce all that well so you don't really need physics in this case.  Once at the floor, the solid vase is switched over to the cell fractured version, and that's adjusted to do more of a collapse-shatter than allow it free reign and it's bits to fly apart, explosion style.

What was done here was to animate the initial tip-over, bounce, rolling action, and final fall.

(use physics if you wish but you'll need to bake that action to ensure nothing changes later)

.

At the impact frame the unbroken version of the vase is swapped for the cell fractured model.

The timeline is held at that frame and the fractured model aligned precisely to the unbroken one by

- Setting the cursor to the unbroken vase's origin point.
  (select it and with SH-S, set the cursor there)
- Set the fractured model to the cursor position, again with SH-S.
- Align the fractured model with the unbroken one.
  ('Object menu --> Transform --> Align to Selected' .
  (Note - this works when 'Transformation Orientation' is set to
  'Normal', not Global)

-=============-

For the inexperienced...

- Switch the Transformation Orientation from Global to 'NORMAL'.
- Select firstly the fractured version, and with SHIFT held, select the solid one.
- Open the 'Object' menu in the window's header --> Transform --> Align to Transformation Orientation.

Both models should then be exactly aligned.

-============-

Still at that frame, swap them over - visually.  The solid to be invisible, the fractured, visible.

Later - NOT NOW, reverse that order at frame 1.  (Visibility and Render icons in the Outliner)

Note -  it helps enormously to link the fractured cells to one of their number so you only have to animate Dynamic physics etc in one, not them all individually.

.

Still at the change-over (impact) frame, switch the cell fracture physics on by ticking the 'Dynamic' box and keyframing that.

It's now safe to go to frame 1.  Untick the Dynamics and keyframe that also.

While you're at frame 1, reverse the visual switching for the two models.
(solid to visible, fracture to invisible)

When played, the solid vase will be seen to hit the floor, collapse and shatter.

[image]